# Why is there a blank line?

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ program:

```
ofstream output("scores.txt");
output<<"John"<<" "<<"T"<<" "<<"Smith"<<" "<<90<<endl;
output<<"Eric"<<" "<<"K"<<" "<<"Jones"<<" "<<103<<endl;
output.close();

ifstream input;
input.open("scores.txt");
string line;
while (!input.eof()) {
    getline(input, line);
    cout<<line<<endl;
}
input.close();

cout<<"Done";
```

The output is:

```
John T Smith 90
Eric K Jones 103

Done
```

Why is there a blank line between Eric K Jones 103 and Done?

Comment: Is there an empty line at the end of your `scores.txt` file?

Comment: @hlt No. The funny thing is, if I remove the endl, the output is John T Smith 90Eric K Jones 103Done (all on one line). So that can't be the problem.

Comment: remove the last <<endl on the 'Eric' line. It's creating a new line which your loop is picking up

Comment: @SergioS But I want Eric's data to be printed on a new line.

Comment: @Thomas  Eric's data will be printed on a new line already because of the '<<endl;' on the previous line. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Structure your loop like this:

```
while (getline(input, line)) {
    cout<<line<<endl;
}
```

Your duplicate line is because the way your read loop is structured, once you read the last line the `eof` bit is not set yet because `readline` succeeded. Therefore, you iterate one more time, doing a `readline` that *does* set the `eof` bit, then you do `cout<<line<<endl` and that last `endl` is your extra blank line.